# How to loop argument in bash to call a function

Tags: bash, function, arguments

I'd like to apologize if my question had already been asked, but english isn't my native language and I didn't find the answer. I'd like to have a bash script that executes a program I'll call MyProgram, and I want it to run with a fixed number of arguments which consist in random numbers. I'd like to have something like this:

```
./MyProgram for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) $(($RANDOM%200-100))
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: The answers mostly seem to be long-winded variants on `./MyProgram $( for ((i = 0; i < 1000; i++)); do echo $(($RANDOM%200-100)); done )`.  While only 1000 arguments isn't going to stress things, you will need to be careful if the argument list grows by a couple of orders of magnitude (100000 numbers is likely too big, or close to too big, to fit in the argument list).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the only thing that worries me about that suggestion is that while it's a safe practice exactly as-given (dealing with values which can only ever be numbers), it's not safe _in general_ (ie. if the values generated were filenames). The more long-winded approaches are harder to misuse when (re)applying them to real-world use cases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, if you have to worry about spaces in filenames, then the array-based approach suggested by [chepner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26090387/15168) is safe with a little care ensuring that the value added to array is appropriately quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
$RANDOM % 200 - 100
```

is the same as the next perl

```
perl -E 'say int(200*rand() -100)  for (1..1000)'
```

e.g. the

```
perl -E 'say int(200*rand() -100)  for (1..1000)' | xargs -n1 ./MyProgram
```

will run like:

```
./MyProgram -10
./MyProgram 13

... 1000 times ...

./MyProgram 55
./MyProgram -31
```

if you need 1000 args

```
./MyProgram $(perl -E 'say int(200*rand() -100)  for (1..1000)')
```

will produce

```
./MyProgram 5 -41 -81 -79 -14 ... 1000 numbers ... -63 -9 95 -9 -29
```

Answer (score 2):

You (mostly) just have the loop and the actual program call inverted.

```
for ((i=0; i < 1000; i++)); do
    ./MyProgram $((RANDOM%200 - 100))
done
```

If, however, you actually want 1000 different arguments passed to a single call, you have to build up a list first.

```
args=()
for ((i=0; i < 1000; i++)); do
    args+=( $((RANDOM%200 - 100)) )
done
./MyProgram "${args[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @chepner says, you can also use the `for ... in` style of for loop. This looks like:

```
for a in one two three; do
    echo "${a}"
done
```

which would produce the result:

```
one
two
three
```

In other words, the list of words after the `in` part, separated by spaces, is looped over, with each iteration of the loop having a different word in the variable `a`.

To call your program 1000 times (or just modify to produce the list of arguments to run it once as in @chepner's answer) you could then do:

```
for a in $(seq 1 1000); do
    ./MyProgram $((RANDOM%200 - 100))
done
```

where the output of the `seq` command is providing the list of values to loop over. Although the traditional for loop may be more immediately obvious to many programmers, I like `for ... in` because it can be applied in lots of situations. A crude and mostly pointless `ls`, for example:

```
for a in *; do
    echo "${a}"
done
```

`for ... in` is probably the bit of "advanced" bash that I find the most useful, and make use of it very frequently.

Comment: boo, hiss re: demo'ing the platform-dependent `seq` rather than built-in (and thus platform-independent) C-style for-loop functionality used by chepner's answer.

Comment: ...also, `echo "$a"` is more robust than either `echo $a` or `echo ${a}`; both the latter incorrectly files named as, say, `./foo * bar`.

Comment: Point taken, but it was intended as demonstrating a general principle rather than "this is better than the above". `for i in {1..1000}; ...` would be a "better" way of doing it.